# Using Varnish for cache along with IIS

Tags: asp.net, caching, squid

Can we use a Varnish cache server to serve ASP.NET pages? My intention is to host another cache server to improve the performance by caching most accessed and shared data. To rent another IIS server, it will cost again.

Instead can I use any another cache server like Varnish/Squid to store web pages and serve cached data?

Comment: Wouldn't you just be better off using .Net's output caching? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk.aspx

Comment: @thewinchester It wouldn't surprise me at all if the answer to that question was a big fat resounding NO.

Answer (score 3):

Varnish could be used to cache IIS data but the real question is would it make IIS faster in the first place?

This depends on the load of your IIS server of course, but given that caching would be relevant (actually speeding up things) then you probably would benefit from testing other, more scalable options [here is a comparison of Varnish, Nginx, ATS, Lighty, etc.](http://nbonvin.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/serving-small-static-files-which-server-to-use/).

Comment: Ofcourse it wont make IIS faster. But thats never the intention of Varnish. Varnish is a HTTP accelerator, its something that sits in front of your webserver and caches/servers your static pages. That way alot of your traffic never even reaches your webserver.

Comment: Using just .net caching for big sites its not enough, what we did was simply added varnish cluster installed on linux... and fixed the .net backend application to invalidate the varnish cache... That took 95 percent of the requests off the iis.

Comment: It doesn't make IIS faster or slower, it runs the same. Varnish speeds up everything by caching what IIS serves, and is serverd from Varnish! Not IIS!.